# What are the differences between malloc(3posix) and malloc(3)?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc, posix

They need the same header file and the signatures are same.**But their descriptions are different indeed.**What are the differences between malloc(3posix) and malloc(2)?If i see `malloc` is called in a source code, how can know which one is called indeed?

As per the linux programmer's manual, which says:

> MALLOC(3POSIX)                                                 POSIX Programmer's Manual
>   MALLOC(3POSIX)
>
> PROLOG
>          This  manual  page  is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual.  The Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the
>   corresponding
>          Linux manual page for details of Linux behavior), or the interface may not be implemented on Linux.
>
> NAME
>          malloc — a memory allocator
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          #include < stdlib.h >
>
> ```
>    void *malloc(size_t size);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements
>   described here and
>          the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of POSIX.1‐2008 defers to the ISO C standard.
>           The malloc() function shall allocate unused space for an object whose size in bytes is specified by size and whose value is
>   unspecified.
>           The  order  and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to malloc() is unspecified. The pointer returned if the
>   allocation succeeds
>          shall be suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an  object 
>   in  the  space
>          allocated (until the space is explicitly freed or reallocated). Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an object disjoint from
>   any other
>          object. The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space. If the space cannot be allocated, a
>   null pointer
>          shall  be  returned. If the size of the space requested is 0, the behavior is implementation-defined: the value returned shall be
>   either a null
>          pointer or a unique pointer.

and

> MALLOC(3)                                                      Linux Programmer's Manual
>   MALLOC(3)
>
> NAME
>          malloc, free, calloc, realloc - allocate and free dynamic memory
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          #include < stdlib.h >
>
> ```
>    void *malloc(size_t size);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The  malloc()  function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.  If
>   size is 0, then
>          malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().

Comment: `What are the differences between malloc(3posix) and malloc(2)?` None, it's the same `malloc`.

Comment: But their descriptions are different.

Comment: How is it different? (I mean, compare with I don't know, a tree. If I write a description of a tree, and you write a different description of the same tree, does it make that there are two trees? No, there is only one tree with two different descriptions.)

Comment: We know that the PROLOG is a *general* disclaimer, because `malloc()` *is* implemented on Linux.

Comment: If a function is called `malloc` and has the known signature of this function, and is part of an OS runtime for C, then it has to adhere with what `malloc` is expected to do regardless of how it is described, otherwise the runtime is non-standard.

Comment: Maybe you are asking about... `malloc(3p)` is a description of `malloc` on a posix system, `malloc(3)` describes `malloc` on linux system, so you are asking how to check if you are compiling your program on linux?

Comment: I have reedited the question.You could see the "DESCRIPTION" sections are different.So i am a little confused that whether they are same.

Comment: Which parts contradict one another?

Comment: You could see the "DESCRIPTION" sections are different, which are posted in the question.

Comment: Yes, but *where is any contradiction* in those descriptions? One is fuller, the other is functionally adequate. In other words, what does the shorter one say, that disagrees with what the longer description says?